# How to publish standalone Angular component (njsproj) with web application in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, single-page-application

We have a requirement that we need to publish our site to test it local (sitecore). We have a special component for that called webapp.

We now have introduced a new component (njsproj file) which contains our angular application. When I publish  webapp obviously the angular code is not compiled (npm install build etc) and copied to the artifact of the webapp and published.

In my CI CD pipeline I have it al mapped out and working... The build steps: use nodejs, npm install angular cli, npm install, ng build.

How do I set this up properly so that publishing works locally? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can open your njsproj content and add this setting

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

The command is taken from package.json

You see that I add another command to run test in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Angular8:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test", // run this command
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

But I think you can take a look on this article from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) to create angular app

Comment: Thanks man! Im currently working on a powershell solution which I run via publish profile. I will evaluate this solution too :)